# Difference between the result of `step` and `stepinfo` in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using the function `stepinfo` to get the step response of the system. But the information that I get and the information I get from the plot made by `step` doesn't match. For the closed loop system:

```
m1=3; m2=2; k=12; B=6;
p=35.1263; z=4.9686; K=683.9;

s=tf('s');
G=(B*s+k+s^2*m2)/(s^2*(s^2*m1*m2+(m1+m2)*(B*s+k)));
H=K*(s+z)/(s+p);
T=(G*H/(1+G*H));
```

The result of `stepinfo(T)` is

```
ans = 

        RiseTime: 0.3876
    SettlingTime: 1.4245
     SettlingMin: 0.9863
     SettlingMax: 1.1881
       Overshoot: 18.8102
      Undershoot: 0
            Peak: 1.1881
        PeakTime: 0.5756
```

While the graph that results from `step(T,0:1e-3:10)` clearly shows that the response goes over 1.2, which means that the Overshoot is greater than 20 and not 18.81.
[image: step response]

What is the source for the difference?

Comment: what version of matlab are you running? it says 20.94 for me which matches the plot.

Comment: I have Matlab R2012a and as noted it provides the correct answer. If others can confirm this, the problem was likely a bug that got fixed.

Comment: same here ( Overshoot: 20.9442) at Matlab 2012a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be some sort of a bug with the R2009b version. As noted in the comments, I've ran the same code on a machine with R2012a version, and the results of `stepinfo` were:

```
ans = 

    RiseTime: 0.1671
SettlingTime: 1.3591
 SettlingMin: 0.9066
 SettlingMax: 1.2094
   Overshoot: 20.9442
  Undershoot: 0
        Peak: 1.2094
    PeakTime: 0.4604
```

which is the expected result.